# Interesting compile problems in Oracle JDK 1.7, 1.8 - [Compiling depends on order of imports]

Tags: java, eclipse

My teammate may have found an interesting bug in jdk compiler.
It seems to depend on import sequence when trying to compile a class with 3-level nested class.

FrameLayoutCompat.java

```
package com.external;

public class FrameLayoutCompat
{

}
```

First.java

```
package com.nested;

import com.nested.First.Second.Third;
import com.external.FrameLayoutCompat;

public class First
{
    public static class Second extends FrameLayoutCompat
    {
        public static class Third
        {

        }
    }

    public static class Second2
    {
        public static class Third2
        {
            private Third mThird;
        }
    }
}
```

Try to compile FrameLayoutCompat.java First.java

```
javac com/external/FrameLayoutCompat.java
javac com/external/First.java
```

Here's the error.

```
com/nested/First.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    public static class Second extends FrameLayoutCompat
                                       ^
  symbol:   class FrameLayoutCompat
  location: class First
1 error
```

But if we change the code by switching the import sequence. It works.

```
package com.nested;

import com.external.FrameLayoutCompat;
import com.nested.First.Second.Third;

public class First
{
    public static class Second extends FrameLayoutCompat
    {
        public static class Third
        {

        }
    }

    public static class Second2
    {
        public static class Third2
        {
            private Third mThird;
        }
    }
}
```

We tried the ecj, eclipse java compiler, it works also, so it may be a bug in Oracle jdk compiler.It works. Any comment?

```
java -jar ../ecj-4.4.jar -source 1.8 .
```

[Edited]
I have try this to compile. Because other thinks it's better to compile them together. But **the problem is that: the import sequence matters, instead of the 'cannot find symbol' error. Because if you try to change the sequence of import, it works well.**

```
javac -s ../src -d ../build com\external\FrameLayoutCompat.java com\nested\First.java
```

Here's the zip file I saved in Evernote. It's worth a try. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s70/sh/8ed81644-5b90-4008-aa33-3b9e3aa7904a/5f8ba97f96d2132b

[edit]
Find a JPE for this, it's an know issue in JDK for javac command.It can be closed.
[JEP 216: Process Import Statements Correctly](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/216)

Comment: I bet the problem goes away if you compile both .java at once. Compiling single sources when there are circular dependencies just doesn't work very well...

Comment: correct. No error in the compiler, just you not realising your code is dependent on something that hasn't been compiled yet.

Comment: Hi both, that's not the case you mentioned. The reason becasue of this, is that the sequence of import. If I put "import com.external.FrameLayoutCompat;" first, it works, but If I put "import com.external.FrameLayoutCompat;" as the second import. it failed. I have prepare zip file for this. You can have a try, it worth a try if you think it's that simple. I use this command to compile the unzip folder “javac -s ../src -d ../build com\external\FrameL
ayoutCompat.java com\nested\First.java”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is "extends FrameLayoutCompat":

When you use,

```
import com.nested.First.Second.Third;
import com.external.FrameLayoutCompat;
```

you are trying to import the class called "Third" which exists within class Second which exists within class First.

But the Second class is declared as:

```
public static class Second extends FrameLayoutCompat.
```

So it needs FrameLayoutCompat without which it can't compile. And if class Second doesn't compile, then class First won't compile too. And hence the error:

Try commenting

```
// extends FrameLayoutCompat
```

and instead use

```
FrameLayoutCompat layout;
```

and you'd find the order doesn't matter

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's the thing I want to talk about. As I know, there's no matter the sequence of import. Event if I use "import import com.nested.First.Second.Third" first, I should be ok. And strage thing is if I put "import import com.nested.First.Second.Third" second, it works again. Also, in ecipse compiler, both cases work fine. So I wonder whether the spec of JDK imply the import sequence matters in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a know issue in JDK javac tools "7101822: Compiling depends on order of imports". Edit the post and add a link, this should be the right answer.